# Copy contents of a directory to Documents directory

Tags: objective-c, ios, file, for-loop, nsdocumentdirectory

I have a problem, I need to move the contents of a Documents subdirectory to the 'root' of Documents Directory.
To do this, I thought to copy all the contents of the subdirectory to Documents directory and then delete my subdirectory.

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentinbox = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"inbox"]
```

This is how I get the path of Documents directory, and the path of my subdirectory named inbox.

```
 NSArray *inboxContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentinbox error:nil];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
```

Then I create an array with all documents in the subfolder, and initialize the file manager.

Now I have to implement the for cycle that for each document copy the document from the subdirectory to the Documents Directory.

```
for(int i=0;i<[inboxContents count];i++){
  //here there is the problem, I don't know how to copy each file
```

I would like to use the method moveItemAtPath, but I don't know how to get the path of each file.

Hope you can understand my problem, 
Thanks for help 
Nicco

Comment: moveItemAtPath won't work, as you can't delete files from the app bundle directory.

Comment: @H2CO3 The documents directory is not part of the bundle.

Comment: @Joe right, sorry, I misread the question, the usual problem that arises is not being able to write to XXXX.app (which *is* the bundle itself).

Comment: the reason for this is that I need to put to the main Documents directory the file passed after tapping the Open in button. For example, I received a pdf as email attachment and I click open in.. button, my app must put that file into the Documents directory

Answer (score 2):

You can use `moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:` as follows.

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentinbox = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"inbox"];

//Initialize fileManager first
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//You should always check for errors
NSError *error;
NSArray *inboxContents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentinbox error:&error];
//TODO: error handling if inboxContents is nil

for(NSString *source in inboxContents)
{
    //Create the path for the destination by appending the file name
    NSString *dest = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      [source lastPathComponent]];

    if(![fileManager moveItemAtPath:source
                            toPath:dest
                             error:&error])
    {
        //TODO: Handle error
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}
```